# Ubuntu 18.04 - Keyboard shortcuts are not working for the GNOME Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I have an installation of Ubuntu 18 in form of a Virtual Machine, and I am using TurboVNC to connect to it.

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

If I have an open terminal the keyboard shortcuts would work just fine. For example `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `T` adds a new Tab to the terminal. Other apps also respond to keyboard shortcuts. For example pressing `Alt` on FireFox shows the menu bar, or `Alt` + `F4` will close the App. It is just the GNOME Desktop itself which seemingly doesn't respond to the keyboard. For example, I cannot open a new terminal using `Ctrl` +  `Alt` + `T` (this is the setting that I have in keyboard setting). I also cannot logout or shutdown the machine using Shutdown or Logout option in the drop-down menu in upper right corner. Clicking on those buttons does nothing, but lock-screen option works! Not sure if these symptoms are related.

I spent quite some time and looked at some similar questions and complaints. I have tried some of the suggested solutions, none have worked so far. I appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  You mention a *yy* format release twice, but have tagged a *yy.mm* release too??  They are different products (one has GNOME running as a *snap*, the other doesn't)

Comment: I added the output of lsb_release. Thank you.

Comment: which version of ubuntu. Ex: 18.04, 18.10, etc.

Comment: Please correct your heading & question; Ubuntu 18 implies Ubuntu Core 18 and is a different system to 18.04  (see first comment; Ubuntu has had 18 & 18.*yy* releases since 2016 being different products).